# Find the series of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ without using the Taylor series??

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

find the inverse of $\tan(x)$ without using the Taylor series

Comment: What? Your title and body differ a lot.

Comment: Do you want a series representation of $\tan^{-1}$, or are you asking for a different representation?

Comment: yes, I need the common series of inverse tan(x) but without using the Taylor series

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** I suppose that you want the series for $\tan^{-1}(x)$. Remember that $$\tan^{-1}(x) = \int \frac{1}{1+x^2} \ \mathrm{d}x,$$and use the series for $\frac{1}{1+ x^2.}$

Comment: no no this is  impossible because you use the series

Comment: Then your question is not clear enough. The title says something and the body of the question says another. I understood that you wanted to find the series for $\tan^{-1}$ without using its Taylor series. Using my hint you can find it using the Taylor series for *another* function, indirectly.

Comment: ok i ll edit the body

Comment: if you can complete your answer to see it?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\tan^{-1}(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots$, and take the derivative of each side with respect to $x$.

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+\cdots.$$

If $|x|<1$, the left hand side is the sum of the infinite geometric series with first term 1 and common ratio $x^2$.

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2} =1+x^2+x^4+\cdots.$$

Equate the two series for $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ to find the values of $a_i$ in the original series for $\tan^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: But you are using the series

Comment: I'm not using a known Taylor series result. I'm using the formula for an infinite geometric series. I guess I don’t know what you mean by “without using the Taylor series,” but I wouldn’t say to someone who wrote this “But you used the Taylor series.”

Comment: sorry , If can you give me the values of an